# Uploading multiple files using node, multer, express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files using multer. I have three input boxes and one upload button to upload three files at the same time.
As per the client requirement user needs to select one file at a time and after selecting three files, user can upload all the files in one go.

[image: Screenshot of three text boxes and a button]

**HTML**

```
<div ng-show="role == '1'"  class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 form-group">
    <label for="basic-url">Upload Your Image (Passport Size)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control"  file-model="file.upload" name="myFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)"></label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="Submit('customerimage')" value="Upload" >
</div>
<div ng-show="role == '1'"  class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 form-group">                       
    <label for="basic-url">Upload Pan Card image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control"  file-model="file.upload" name="myFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)"></label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="Submit('pancardimage')" value="Upload" >
</div>
<div ng-show="role == '1'"  class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 form-group">                   
    <label for="basic-url">Upload Bank Passbook image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control"   file-model="file.upload" name="myFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(thi`enter code here`s.files)"></label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="Submit('bankimage')" value="Upload" >
</div>
```

**Server.js**

```
var multer=require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
          destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'public/uploads/images/');
          },
          filename: function (req, file, cb) {
              if(! file.originalname.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|JPEG|JPG|PNG)$/)){

                  var err=new Error();
                  err.code="filetype";
                  return cb(err);
              }else{
                  cb(null,Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname);
              }

            //cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
          }
    });
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('myFile');
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
      upload(req, res, function (err) {
              console.log(req.file);

         if (err) {
            if(err.code=='LIMIT_FILE_SIZE'){
                res.json({success:false,message:'file is tool arge'});
            }else if(err.code=='filetype'){
                res.json({success:false,message:'file type is invalid'});
            }else{

                res.json({success:false,message:'file is not selected'});
            }
        }
      else{
          if(!req.file){
              res.json({success:false,message:'no file selected'});
          }
          else{
          console.log(req.file);
               res.json({success:true,message: req.file});
          }
        }

        // Everything went fine
      });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.file={};
    $scope.Submit=function(name){
        $scope.name = name;
        uploadFile.upload($scope.file).then(function(data){
            if(data.data.success){
                $scope.alert='alert alert-success';
                $scope.message=data.data.message;
                $scope.file={};
                $scope.newCustomer[$scope.name] = 'uploads/images/' + data.data.message.filename;
            }else{
                $scope.alert='alert alert-danger';
                $scope.message=data.data.message;
                $scope.file={};
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.photoChanged=function(files){
     if(files.length >0 && files[0].name.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$/)){
         var file=files[0];
         var fileReader=new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
         fileReader.onload=function(e){
             $timeout(function(){
                     $scope.thumbnail={};
                         $scope.thumbnail.dataUrl=e.target.result;
             });
         }
     }
     else{
         $scope.thumbnail={};
         $scope.message=false;
     }
 };
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive("fileModel",['$parse',function($parse){
      return{
              restrict:"A",
              link:function(scope,element,attrs){
                  var parsedFile=$parse(attrs.fileModel);
                  var parsedFileSetter=parsedFile.assign;

                  element.bind('change',function(){
                      scope.$apply(function(){
                            parsedFileSetter(scope,element[0].files[0]);

                      });
                  });
              }
      };

}]);
```

**Service**

```
//var app = angular.module('MLMApp',[]);
app.service("uploadFile",function($http){
      this.upload=function(file){
            var fd=new FormData();
            fd.append('myFile',file.upload);
            return $http.post('/upload',fd,{
                 transformRequest:angular.identity,
                 headers:{'Content-Type':undefined}
                 //headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data}
            });
      };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append each of your input fields to your form before passing it to your middleware.

I see that all 3 of your inputs use the same *file-model*, I am not sure if this creates an array or overwrite each other.  But you could try the following

try this in case of array:

```
service.uploadFile = function(file){
    var fd = new FormData();
    for(var i = 0; i < file.upload.length; i++){
        fd.append('myFile', file.upload[i]);
    }
    return $http.post('/upload',fd,{
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    });
}
```

In the case that they overwrite each other, try this:

```
service.uploadFile = function(file){
    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('image1', file.upload1);
    fd.append('image2', file.upload2);
    fd.append('image3', file.upload3);

    return $http.post('/upload',fd,{
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks Jae..I solved it by different technique..Thanks

Comment: @GurunathBhopale could you explain how you solved your problem? Because I have the same problem